# Resolv.conf: presence of 'search localdomain' fails correct DNS lookup

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

Scenario:

- Attempt to resolve host named 'puppet' in domain 'puppet.mydomain.com'
- Resolution is successful if the resolv.conf file does *not* include search directive for 'localdomain' and *only* the domain 'mydomain.com'.

Resolv.conf working:

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
search mydomain.com
```

Resolv.conf failed:

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
search localdomain mydomain.com
```

- The system is multihomed
- Both interfaces have "domain-name mydomain.com" and "domain-search mydomain.com" directives in /etc/network/interfaces.

How can the resolution fail with an additional domain? Shouldn't resolution be attempted for all listed domains?

What do I need to configure to prevent localdomain from being added to the resolv.conf file?

Comment: What result do you get if you look up `puppet.localdomain` directly? Use `dig` or another DNS tool that produces good diagnostics. Perhaps this name resolves in a way you don't expect which causes the subsequent query for `puppet.mydomain.com` to not be tried.

Comment: You say «Both interfaces have "domain-name mydomain.com" and "domain-search mydomain.com" directives in /etc/network/interfaces.» Did you mean to say that both interfaces have `dns-domain mydomain.com` and `dns-search mydomain.com` in /e/n/i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to configure to prevent `localdomain` from being added to the resolv.conf file?

First make sure that the resolvconf package is installed and that /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Second make sure that there are no `domain` or `search` lines in any of the files in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/.

Third, find out where `localdomain` is coming from. If your interface is configured via DHCP then it's probably being sent by the DHCP server. Then fix the DHCP server configuration. If NetworkManager is involved, use the Connection Editor to make sure that `localdomain` is not in the `Additional search domains` field on the `IPv4 Settings` tab of any active connections.

Comment: `egrep -r 'search|domain' /{etc,run}/resolvconf/ /etc/dhcp/`

Comment: Relevant instructions can be found here: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/How-to-change-quot-option-domain-name-localdomain-quot-in-vmnet8/td-p/2596106

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where resolution without a dot tries to resolve to the localdomain, which I do not want.
localdomain is added to the symlinked /etc/resolv.conf file on Ubuntu 18.04 which is managed by systemd-resolved according to the file comments.

I found some info on how to set search domains but it does not explain the presence of this specific domain, I am guessing it's some kind of default.

It's possible to set search domains like this :

```
sudo systemd-resolve --set-domain=local --set-domain=prod.ldap --interface=enxxxxxxxxx
```

If anyone can explain where and why localdomain is always present it's appreciated.
The above command can be used to set per interface search domains, which seems like a good workaround - this does not survive a reboot.

Another option to set search domains is to use the network manager GUI tha was hidden, run from a terminal:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

There you can set search domains, those will be appended to localdmain, not replace it.
I hope this helps anyone.